# Powershell - Having difficulty in ignoring the header row (first row) and footer row (last row) in file

Tags: performance, powershell, csv

I am looking to find extra delimiters in my file on a line by line basis.
I would, however would like to ignore the header row (first row) and the footer row (last row) in the file and just focus on the file detail.

I am not sure on how to ignore the first and last row using the `ReadLine()` method.  I DO NOT want to alter the file in any way, this script is used just to identify rows in the CSV file that have extra delimiters.

Please note: The file I am looking to search has millions of rows and in order to do that I have to rely on the `ReadLine()` method rather than the `Get-Content` approach.

I did try to use `Select-Object -Skip 1 | Select-Object -SkipLast 1` in my `Get-Content` statement inputting the value into `$measure` but I didn't get the desired result.

For example:

```
H|Transaction|2017-10-03 12:00:00|Vendor --> This is the Header
D|918a39230a098134|2017-08-31 00:00:00.000|2017-08-15 00:00:00.000|SLICK-2340|...
D|918g39230b095134|2017-08-31 00:00:00.000|2017-08-15 00:00:00.000|EX|SRE-68|...
T|1268698 Records --> This is Footer
```

Basically, I want my script to ignore the header and footer, and use the first data row (`D|918...`) as the example of a correct record and the other detail records to be compared against it for error (in this example the second detail row should be returned, because there an invalid delimiter in the the field (`EX|SRE-68...`).

When I tried using `-skip 1` and `-skiplast 1` in the `get-content` statement, the process is still using the header row as a comparison and returning all detail records as invalid records.

Here's what I have so far...

<sup>Editor's note: Despite the stated intent, this code does use the *header* line (the 1st line) to determine the reference column count.</sup>

```
$File = "test.csv"
$Delimiter = "|"

$measure = Get-Content -Path $File | Measure-Object
$lines = $measure.Count

Write-Host "$File has ${lines} rows."

$i = 1

$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($File)
$line = $reader.ReadLine()
$reader.Close()
$header = $line.Split($Delimiter).Count

$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($File)
try
{
    for()
    {
        $line = $reader.ReadLine()
        if($line -eq $null) { break }
        $c = $line.Split($Delimiter).Count
        if($c -ne $header -and $i -ne${lines})
        {
            Write-Host "$File - Line $i has $c fields, but it should be $header"
        }
        $i++
    }
}

finally
{
    $reader.Close()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Now that we know that performance matters**, here's a solution that uses only `[System.IO.TextFile].ReadLine()` (as a faster alternative to `Get-Content`) to read the large input file, and does so only *once*:

- No up-front counting of the number of lines via `Get-Content ... | Measure-Object`,
- No separate instance of opening the file just to read the header line; keeping the file open after reading the header line has the added advantage that you can just keep reading (no logic needed to skip the header line).

---

```
$File = "test.csv"
$Delimiter = "|"

# Open the CSV file as a text file for line-based reading.
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($File)

# Read the lines.
try {

  # Read the header line and discard it.
  $null = $reader.ReadLine()

  # Read the first data line - the reference line - and count its columns.
  $refColCount = $reader.ReadLine().Split($Delimiter).Count

  # Read the remaining lines in a loop, skipping the final line.
  $i = 2 # initialize the line number to 2, given that we've already read the header and the first data line.
  while ($null -ne ($line = $reader.ReadLine())) { # $null indicates EOF

    ++$i # increment line number

    # If we're now at EOF, we've just read the last line - the footer - 
    # which we want to ignore, so we exit the loop here.
    if ($reader.EndOfStream) { break }

    # Count this line's columns and warn, if the count differs from the
    # header line's.
    if (($colCount = $line.Split($Delimiter).Count) -ne $refColCount) {
      Write-Warning "$File - Line $i has $colCount fields rather than the expected $refColCount."
    }

  } 

} finally {

  $reader.Close()

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Any reason your using Read Line? The Get-Content your doing will already load the entire CSV into memory, so I'd save that to a variable and then use a loop to go through (starting at 1 to skip the first line).

So something like this:

```
$File = "test.csv"
$Delimiter = "|"

$contents = Get-Content -Path $File
$lines = $contents.Count

Write-Host "$File has ${lines} rows."

$header = $contents[0].Split($Delimiter).count

for ($i = 1; $i -lt ($lines - 1); $i++)
{ 
    $c = $contents[$i].Split($Delimiter).Count
    if($c -ne $header)
    {
        Write-Host "$File - Line $i has $c fields, but it should be $header"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You the_sw and mklement0 for your help!

Files that I am attempting to search through are sometimes millions of rows large and when using the get-content method, it seems to perform rather poorly.  For example, it takes about a half hour for a file that is 500,000 rows large, using the get-content method.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Note: This answer was written before the OP clarified that performance was paramount and that a `Get-Content`-based solution was therefore not an option.  My [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46634810/45375) now addresses that.

***This* answer** may still be of interest for a ***slower*, but more concise, PowerShell-idiomatic solution.**</sup>

[the_sw's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46558203/45375) shows that you can use PowerShell's own `Get-Content` cmdlet to conveniently read a file, without needing to resort to direct use of the .NET Framework.

**PSv5+** enables an **idiomatic single-pipeline solution** that is more concise and more memory-efficient - it processes lines one by one - albeit **at the expense of performance**; especially with large files, however, you may not want to read them in all at once, so a pipeline solution is preferable.

<sup>PSv5+ is required due to use of `Select-Object`s `-SkipLast` parameter.</sup>

```
$File = "test.csv"
$Delimiter = '|'

Get-Content $File | Select-Object -SkipLast 1 | ForEach-Object { $i = 0 } {
  if (++$i -eq 1) { 
    return # ignore the actual header row
  } elseif ($i -eq 2) { # reference row
    $refColumnCount = $_.Split($Delimiter).Count
  } else { # remaining rows, except the footer, thanks to -SkipLast 1
    $columnCount = $_.Split($Delimiter).Count
    if ($columnCount -ne $refColumnCount) {
      "$File - Line $i has $columnCount fields rather than the expected $refColumnCount."
    }
  }
}
```